# I get error "Object required":[string:"Hostname"]'

Tags: vbscript

```
Dim Computer, WshNetwork
Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Computer = WshNetwork.ComputerName
Dim FSO, OutPutFile
Const ForWriting = 2
Const ForAppending = 8
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim EndFile, wsusscn2
EndFile = "c:\Scripts\" & Computer & ".csv" ' choose the location for the output
wsusscn2 = "c:\Scripts\wsusscn2.cab" ' choose location of the cab file
Set OutPutFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(EndFile, ForWriting, True)
Set UpdateSession = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session")
Set UpdateServiceManager = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.ServiceManager")
Set UpdateService = UpdateServiceManager.AddScanPackageService( _
     "Offline Sync Service", wsusscn2)
Set UpdateSearcher = UpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher()
UpdateSearcher.ServerSelection = 3 ' ssOthers
UpdateSearcher.ServiceID = UpdateService.ServiceID
Set searchResult = UpdateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0")
Set Updates = SearchResult.Updates
OutPutFile.WriteLine "Missing Patches " & Date & Computer  
OutPutFile.WriteLine "." OutPutFile.WriteLine "."   
If searchResult.Updates.Count = 0 Then
  OutPutFile.WriteLine "There are no applicable updates."
  WScript.Quit
End If
For I = 0 To searchResult.Updates.Count - 1
  Set Update = searchResult.Updates.Item(I)
  OutPutFile.WriteLine Update.Title
Next
OutPutFile.Close
WScript.Quit
```

Answer (score 0):

`Set` statement assigns an *object reference* to a variable or property, or associates a *procedure reference* with an event. This is not your case, as you   ask for `ComputerName` *property* of the `WshNetwork` object. Hence, instead of `set Computer = WshNetwork.ComputerName`, use

```
Computer = WshNetwork.ComputerName
```

Comment: Hi Josefz, i have modified and ran the script with admin privilege, getting permission denied error,